# How to format user input into time

Tags: c#

I am writing a simple class in C# that all it does is print three float variables to a DOS console (hour, minutes, seconds). The output is something like this: Hour = 3, Minutes = 15, Seconds = 0. But I want to know how would I go about in formatting it to show 3:15:00 rather than Hour = 3, Minutes = 15, Seconds = 0

This is the method I created that prints out the info:

```
/// <summary>
/// Prints the time to the console
/// </summary>
public void PrintTime()
{
    Console.WriteLine(pHour.ToString() + ":" + pMinutes.ToString() + ":" + Seconds.ToString());
}
```

Can someone help me figure out how to format this? I went online and found out about DateTime but it requires the date as well and I don't need to add that for this homework. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Hours and Minutes should not be floats (and maybe not seconds, depending on what you want).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the string format that [Console.WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx) provides:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1:00}:{2:00}", pHour, pMinutes, Seconds);
```

Comment: Should probably use the `00` formatter for minutes and seconds at least `{0}:{1:00}:{2:00}`

Comment: @Daniel Peñalba yes thatw orked, but... how would I arrange it to be like 03:15:00 ?

Comment: @user3838697 just use the `00` for the format string for the hour as well.

Comment: it still showing up 3:15:0 and I have the code like:

'Console.WriteLine("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", pHour.ToString(), pMinutes.ToString(), pSeconds.ToString());'

Comment: @user3838697 remove the `ToString` calls you have on each variable.

Comment: @user3838697 Just to follow up the format strings are only used if the matching argument implements `IFormattable` which `float` does, but `string` does not.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit out of context. One more method is to use `DateTime` class to output the string

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy MM dd HH:mm:ss.fff tt", [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

The advantage of this method is easy insertion of separators in Date. Disadvantage is you cant insert your normal text inside the format string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a DateTime object to represent your Time and just disregard the Date part.  Or you could use a TimeSpan object to accomplish a similar feat.

Or, just disregard both entirely and print out your input values as is:

```
    int hours = 5;
    int minutes = 55;
    int seconds = 7;

    DateTime dt = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, hours, minutes, seconds);

    TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(hours, minutes, seconds);

    Console.WriteLine("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", dt.Hour, dt.Minute, dt.Second);
    Console.WriteLine("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds); // This is actually not needed for using a TimeSpan, see next line.
    Console.WriteLine(ts);
    Console.WriteLine("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", hours, minutes, seconds);
```

In action 
https://dotnetfiddle.net/6lUwnR

Note that weird stuff will happen if you pass in out of range values in some cases, so make sure to validate your input! :)